# Can I perform a merge operation in TFS while i have checked out files?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, merge

I am trying to perform a merge operation between two branches: main and dev
and I was wondering if it can be performed while I have some files checked out by some team members. Since I don't want to interrupt my team work every time I perform a merge operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can have changes *checked out* in the source or the target, however there can be no *locks* on the target of the merge.

If a user has a check-in or a check-out lock on a file in the merge target then you will not be able to pend any changes (merge changes or otherwise).  That user will need to unlock the files.

If you have TFS set up to "disable multiple checkouts", then acquiring a lock at check out is required.  You can turn this off in:

> Team  > Team Project Settings > Source Control > Allow Multiple Checkouts

Comment: then why do i get an error saying : unable to perform the operation on "checked out files"? is there any way to perform the merge without getting that error message?

Comment: @Yolanda Good question, I updated my answer with some information about locks.

Comment: You should perform merge operations in a separate workspace to you development. That will avoid any issues

Comment: That will prevent *your* changes from conflicting but will not help if somebody has a lock.